# make wait function do something on and on if it fails

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am very beginner with Selenium and Java to write tests.
I know that I can use the code below to try to click on a web element twice (or as many time as I want):

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    try{
             wait.until(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                  (By.xpath("//button[text()='bla bla ..']"))).click();
              break;
       }catch(Exception e){ }
 }
```

but i was wondering if there is anything like passing a veriable to the wait function to make it do it ith times itself, something like:

```
wait.until(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                      (By.xpath("//button[text()='bla bla ..']"),2)).click();
```

For example in here 2 may mean that try to do it two times if it fails, do we have such a thing?

Comment: I am curious of doing this since I don't see the reason for doing this. Why don't just extend the waiting time ?

Comment: @KitFung the element is visiable and clickable but when we click on it for many other reasons it may fail, so I need to do it again

Comment: Hi, if you want to perform click again when exception occurs, then try with loop while or do/while by cross checking exception.. is it looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at FluentWait, I think this will cover your use case specifying appropriate timeout and polling interval.
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find something in the set of *ExpectedConditions* that does what you are wanting you can always write your own.

The *WebDriverWait.until* method can be passed either a *com.google.common.base.Function* or *com.google.common.base.Predicate*.  If you create your own Function implementation then it's good to note that any non-null value will end the wait condition.  For Predicate the apply method simply needs to return true.

Armed with that I do believe there's very little you can't do with this API.  The feature you're asking about probably does not exist out of the box, but you have full capability to create it.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html

Best of Luck.

---

**Untested Snippet**

```
final By locator = By.xpath("");
      Predicate<WebDriver> loopTest = new Predicate<WebDriver>(){
        @Override
        public boolean apply(WebDriver t) {
            int tryCount = 0;
            WebElement element = null;
            while (tryCount < 2) {
                tryCount++;
                try {
                    element = ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator).apply(t);
                    //If we get this far then the element resolved.  Break loop.
                    break;
                } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException timeout) {
                    //FIXME LOG IT
                }

            }
            return element != null;
        }
      };
      WebDriverWait wait;
      wait.until(loopTest);
```